# Spring Autowire with Bean creation in same class results in :Requested bean is currently in creation Error*

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I know the error is self explanatory, but when I remove the setting of rest template from constructor to @Autowired @Qualifier("myRestTemplate") private RestTemplate restTemplate, it works.

Just want to know how can I do that in constructor if the same class has bean definition of what I am trying to autowire?

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'xxx': Requested bean is currently in
>   creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

```
@Component
public class xxx {

 private RestTemplate restTemplate;

 @Autowired
 public xxx(@Qualifier("myRestTemplate") RestTemplate restTemplate) {
   this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
 }

 @Bean(name="myRestTemplate")
 public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
 }

}
```

Comment: Should not be a problem. The above implementation should work as is, just remove `@Autowired` from you constructor.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala That will not work as I don't have a default constructor, so I need Autowired with this constructor.

Comment: Got your point. Why do you want to create `@Bean` in the same class? Could you initialize it in `ApplicationInitializer` (The class which is annotated as `@Configuration`) class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) methods in a regular `@Component` annotated class are processed in what is known as *lite-mode*.

I don't know why you'd want to do this. If your `xxx` class controls the instantiation of the `RestTemplate`, there's not much reason not to do it yourself in the constructor (unless you mean to expose it to the rest of the context, but then there are better solutions).

In any case, for Spring to invoke your `getRestTemplate` factory method, it needs an instance of `xxx`. To create an instance of `xxx`, it needs to invoke its constructor which expects a `RestTemplate`, but your `RestTemplate` is currently in construction.

You can avoid this error by making `getRestTemplate` `static`.

```
@Bean(name="myRestTemplate")
public static RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

In this case, Spring doesn't need an `xxx` instance to invoke the `getRestTemplate` factory method.

Comment: Yes, "but then there are better solutions" drove me to move Bean creation in @configuration, and it works fine now, many thanks.