# Error creating bean with name 'registrationController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder';

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

This is the error that appeared during compilation:

Error creating bean with name 'registrationController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService';

I am assuming that in the Registration for private UserRepo userRepo; does not find bin.I have no more ideas what could be wrong.Help me figure out why I get this error.

RegistrationController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class RegistrationController {

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;

@GetMapping
public String registration(){
    return "registration";
}

@PostMapping
public String processRegistration(RegistrationForm registrationForm){
    userRepo.save(registrationForm.toUser(passwordEncoder));
    return "redirect:/login";
}

}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

// шифрование пароля
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder() );
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/home","login","registration").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();

}
```

interface UserRepo

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User,Long> {
  User findByUsername(String name);
}
```

Log

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 
 'registrationController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryUserDetailsManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager]: Factory method 'inMemoryUserDetailsManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'encoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at com.security.Registration.RegistrationApplication.main(RegistrationApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean 
  with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
  with name 'inMemoryUserDetailsManager' defined in class path resource 
  [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class]: 
  Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
  org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
  [org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager]: Factory method 
  'inMemoryUserDetailsManager' threw exception; nested exception is 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
   'encoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

DetailsService

```
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
UserRepo userRepository;


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
  UsernameNotFoundException {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
  }
}
```

Comment: Last line of the stacktrace says this `'encoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference` which is pretty much self explanatory. There would be circular reference to the dependencies being injected which results in this error.

Comment: I don't quite understand what to do in this case. I need it in the controller to encrypt the password ... What should I do then?

Comment: Could you provide UserDetailsService implementation?

Comment: Added to the description

Comment: Your `User` class is `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` or your custom user ?

Comment: my custom user.

Comment: I use your code to test it work fine only problems is `@NoRepositoryBean` in UserRepo. `@NoRepositoryBean` mean you want to abstract the Repo and don't want the Spring to implement. Did you try remove the `@NoRepositoryBean` ?

Comment: Yes, there it should be

Answer (score 0):

Denis.
The last line of the stacktrace says:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
   'encoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

This means that "encoder" bean is at it's creation stage at the time you are trying to use it inside `configure` method. Similar problem was already solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710912/spring-autowire-with-bean-creation-in-same-class-results-in-requested-bean-is-c) question. I think you should do the same as the answer to those question suggests - make `encoder()` method static.

Comment: This really solved some of the problems.But there is one more.(Field userRepo in com.security.Registration.controller.RegistrationController required a bean of type 'com.security.Registration.repositories.UserRepo' that could not be found.)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you're creating the `PasswordEncoder` in the same class that you're injecting it.

The best solution is to not autowire the `PasswordEncoder` (or the `CurrentUserService`) at all.

It appears, those instances are only used in the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method, which is redundant.

Registering a `PasswordEncoder` and `UserDetailsService` as a bean is enough for Spring Security to detect them and use them in your configuration.

So just remove `@Autowired` from `PasswordEncoder`.